# How can I print integer in triangle form

Tags: php, algorithm, complexity-theory

I want to print integer in triangle form which look like this

```
    1
   121
  12321
```

I tried this but I do not get the actual result

```
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
 {
    for($j=3;$j>=$i;$j--)
    {
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
   for($k=1;$k<=$i;$k++)
    {
      echo $k;
    }
   if($i>1)
    {
      for($m=$i; $m>=1; $m--)
         {
           echo $m;
         }
     }      
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output of this code is:

```
   1
  1221
 123321
```

Where am I going wrong, please guide me.

Comment: Voted to re-close. "While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers** " since the fix is simply "use the correct loop logic" and can't be explained further. I'm glad you found your solution.

Comment: @MikeB So because the answer sucks the question should be closed? I don't follow.

Comment: @Jack I can't see an embellished answer satisfying the trivial requirements in the close message. The gross change is 2 chars and net is 0 and can't be explained in a manner other than "learn how to nest loops and increment counters". I understand we probably disagree about what qualifies as an acceptable question on SO. To me this is low quality - you're entitled to think otherwise.

Comment: What is going on here? Guys should solve home work on their own and not earn 10 ups for others solving them for them. Homeworks are meant to teach them, also teach them to solve a problem **to it's end**.. Jesus said: "Give a man a fish and he can eat one day, ..." Moderators who deleted my one line comment: "Do your homework on your own" are obviously not competent.

Comment: @hek2mgl The PHP chat had a lot to do with it

Comment: @MikeB Yeah looks like. Would not have expected that. Seems these guys tell *this* today and *that* tomorrow. And it looks like they love X-mas trees ;)

Comment: @MikeB I agree, but this is obviously has potential to bring about epic algorithms, that's why everyone's going to like the question

Comment: @pythonian29033 If epic algorithms and clever (yet meaningless) solutions are your thing then try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MikeB as I said; I agreed with your initial argument, but there are many such questions here on SO that came to be frequented by SO users

Answer (score 4):

Another integer solution:

```
$n = 9; 
print str_pad ("&#10029;",$n," ",STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
    print str_pad ("", $n - $i);
    for ($ii=-$i; $ii<=$i; $ii++){
      if ($i % 2 != 0 && $ii % 2 == 0)
        print "&#" . rand(10025,10059) . ";";
      else print $i - abs($ii) + 1;
    }
    print PHP_EOL;
}

        ✭
        1 
       1✬1 
      12321 
     1❊3✪3✳1 
    123454321 
   1✼3✶5❃5❈3✸1
  1234567654321 
 1✾3✯5✿7❉7✫5✷3✶1 
12345678987654321
```

Or if you already have the string, you could do:

```
$n = 9; $s = "12345678987654321"; $i = 1;

while ($i <= $n)
   echo str_pad ("", $n-$i) . substr ($s,0,$i - 1) . substr ($s,-$i++) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
 {
    for($j=3;$j>$i;$j--)
    {
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
   for($k=1;$k<$i;$k++) /** removed = sign*/
    {
      echo $k;
    }
   if($i>=1) /**added = sign*/
    {
      for($m=$i; $m>=1; $m--)
         {
           echo $m;
         }
     }      
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Try this.

**Details:**

1. Your loop is not proper as  in case of `for($k=1;$k<=$i;$k++)`, this will print the 
   repeated number when check the condition for less then and again for equals to.
   So remove the equals sign.
2. reason to add the eqaul sign in `if($i>=1)`  is that the first element will not print if there will not be equals as first it will be print by for loop from where removed the equal sign.

Your output will be this:

```
   1
  121
 12321
```

Comment: @hek2mgl The OP is stacked and I am helping of their. That' it.

Comment: @hek2mgl: So what? He tried, he's stuck, he's asking for help. What difference does it make where he got the problem?

Comment: yes, at least the OP has his own code, there are many who come here with nothing, at least the OP has tried

Comment: This answer could be a lot better with a more detailed explanation why the code didn't work.

Comment: @MikeB: Let's continue this discussion over chat in the PHP room.

Comment: @Jack I have indicated with comments in the answer as you can see. so I want to what details about you are saying. plz let me know.

Comment: Yes, I know you have added comments ... but they just say "added this" or "removed that" ... that's not an explanation imho.

Comment: @Jack I have added some part in to describe the answer hope this will be good to understand.

Answer (score 1):

For all the x-mas lovers:

```
$max = 9; # can be 2 .. 9
for($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    $line = (str_pad('', $max - $i));
    for($ii = 1; $ii <= $i; $ii++) {
        $line .= $ii;
    }   
    for($ii = $i-1; $ii > 0; $ii--) {
        $line .= $ii;
    }   
    echo $line . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
        1
       121
      12321
     1234321
    123454321
   12345654321
  1234567654321
 123456787654321
12345678987654321
```

Amazing what computers are able to achieve nowadays! Isn't it?

Comment: Where are the Christmas balls and decoration?

Comment: @Jack No decorations so far.. :)

Comment: @Jack some bells and whistles below.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but here's yet another solution that uses a "for" loop with two initialization variables and a ternary-based incrementer/decrementer. It's an unorthodox use of a "for" loop, but it's still perfectly valid and arguably makes the code more elegant and easier to follow. I chose to add space before and after each semicolon and omit all other space inside the parentheses so it's easier to visualize each of the three pieces of the "for" loop (initialization, condition, increment/decrement):

```
$count = 9;
echo "<pre>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
    echo str_pad("",$count-$i," ",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    for ( $j=1,$up=true ; $j>0 ; $up?$j++:$j-- ) {
        echo $j;
        if ($j==$i) {$up = false;}
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
        1
       121
      12321
     1234321
    123454321
   12345654321
  1234567654321
 123456787654321
12345678987654321
```